# If I uninstall Evolution but keep evolution-data-server, will my Google address book still sync?

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, google-contacts

Although more common on Linux, I'm asking this here because Evolution is cross-platform.

The situation is: I have all of my contacts on Google, and before Ubuntu 11.10, Evolution was the Calendar/Contact manager; 11.10 switches this to Thunderbird. I like Thunderbird, and would use it assuming I don't have to have a million other things installed to make it work. Luckily, [Mike Conley is getting TB to sync with EVS](http://mikeconley.ca/blog/2011/03/15/my-campaign-to-get-thunderbird-integrated-into-ubuntu-natty-narwhal-continues/).

I tried installing just the data server, but had no way to configure the Google address book. Installing evolution allowed me to add the contacts, and they are visible in Thunderbird. If I un-install Evolution, will EVS continue to sync it? or will it stale?